# Get BasicAuth credentials from HttpContext?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-7.0

Can I get the used BasicAuth credentials from a `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext` object somehow?

Comment: Have you tried `context.Request.Headers.Authorization`? That seems like the natural starting point.

Comment: Depending on what you're trying to achieve, you might want to implement an `AuthenticationHandler` for handling basic auth credentials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the `Authorization` header from `HttpContext.Request.Headers` (`ctx.Request.Headers.Authorization` or `ctx.Request.Headers[HeaderNames.Authorization]` the former being alias for the latter). It should contain something like `Basic .....` where the second part stores [credentials as user ID/password pairs, encoded using base64](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication#basic_authentication_scheme).